# How to select group of distinct rows from the table

Tags: sql, select

Let's assume, a table has the following rows

`ID   Name     Value
1    Apple    Red
1    Taste    Sour
2    Apple    Yellow
2    Taste    Sweet
3    Apple    Red
3    Taste    Sour
4    Apple    Green
4    Taste    Tart
5    Apple    Yellow
5    Taste    Sweet`

I wonder, how can I select ID's corresponding to distinct combination of Apple and Taste? For example, ID=1 corresponds to red sour apple and ID=3 can be omitted in the query result. Similarly, ID=2 is for yellow sweet apple and ID=5 can be excluded from the query result, etc. A valid query result can be any of the following ID sets: (1,2,4), (1,4,5), (2,3,4) etc.

Comment: please tag the rdbms you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The query or the model could be improved with more understanding of the problem.

But assuming the model is correct and the problem is presented as this, this would be my quick approach.

```
SELECT MIN(a.ID) as ID
FROM Table a
INNER JOIN Table b ON a.ID = b.ID AND a.Name > b.Name
GROUP BY a.Value, b.Value
```

This query is joining the table with itself using the ID. But because you would have four lines for each possible combination (Ex.: Apple-Apple, Taste-Taste, Apple-Taste and Taste-Apple), you need to state not only that they are different (Because you would still have Apple-Taste and Taste-Apple) but that one of them is bigger than the other (That way you choose to have Apples on one side of the join and Tastes in the other). That's why there is the `a.Name > b.Name`.

You then group by both the values, stating that you don't want to have more than one combination of Apple values and Taste values. Resulting in only three lines.

The Select I think it depends of the RDBMS (I used SQL Server syntax), and it's selecting the lowest ID. You don't care, so you could choose Min or Max. Min results in lines with 1,2,4. Max would result in 3,4,5.

Comment: Perfect! Thank you, Edu.